# How to upgrade ClamAV on Ubuntu Hardy Heron 8.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude, ubuntu-8.04, clamav

I'm running a server on Ubuntu Hardy Heron 8.04 LTS, and when I installed ClamAV via aptitude, it installed version 0.94. That version has now been EOL'ed, but when I run "aptitude upgrade", it doesn't update ClamAV to the more recent version (0.96).

I then followed [these instructions on Installing ClamAV from the PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV), but when I did that, I get a message saying "The following packages have been kept back: ... clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam ..."

Does anyone know how to get Ubuntu 8.04 to do this update via aptitude or apt-get (I'm hoping to avoid having to compile from source, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it messed up my server last night. I am running Debian Lenny though.
I had to add debian-volatile repository to be able to upgrade to 0.95.3.

You need to add `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-clamav/ppa/ubuntu hardy main` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `apt-get update` After that `apt-get upgrade clamav`

If `apt-get upgrade` does not work, do

`apt-get install clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam`

Comment: services.list? I don't have this file on my system. I think you mean to edit sources.list. I posted this an hour ago, guess I didn't use gray blocks.

Comment: yes, `sources.list`, sorry. typo.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had to do this yesterday, I added ppa to the sources.list, added the key, did an 'apt-get update' and then 'apt-get install''d each package. What happens when you try to 'apt-get install' the packages directly rather then through an upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

If it says packages have been "held back" do a sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.  That'll get them.